# footer wont fill the full width of the page

Tags: html, css, width, carousel, footer

I'm trying to get the footer to span the full width of the page but for some reason it leaves a blank space to the right and left. Also I cant get my social media icons to center in the middle of the footer. I have a carousel at the top of the page that may be affecting the footer but I don't know for sure

```html
<div class="carousel" data-interval="5000">
<section class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="container">
      <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="item active">
          <img src="download.jpg" alt="Chicago" style="width:100%;">
          </div>
          <div class="item">
          <img src="download.jpg" alt="Chicago" style="width:100%;">
          </div>
          <div class="item">
          <img src="download.jpg"" alt="Chicago" style="width:100%;">
          </div>
          <div class="item">
          <img src="download.jpg" alt="Chicago" style="width:100%;">
          </div>
          <div class="item">
          <img src="download.jpg" alt="Chicago" style="width:100%;">
          </div>
        </div>  
</div>
```

```css
#footer {
 height: 60px;
 background: grey;
 width: 100%;
 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <footer id="footer"> 
   <a href="https://www.instagram.com/">
    <img class="instagram" src="instagram.png">
   </a>
   <a href="https://twitter.com/">
    <img class="icon" src="twitter.png">
   </a>
   <a href="https://www.facebook.com/">
    <img class="icon" src="facebook.png">
   </a>   
  </footer>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `container-fluid` instead of `container` in footer div

And for centering the images use `text-center` class on footer tag.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <footer id="footer" class="text-center">    
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/">
                <img class="instagram" src="instagram.png">
            </a>
            <a href="https://twitter.com/">
                <img class="icon" src="twitter.png">
            </a>
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/">
                <img class="icon" src="facebook.png">
            </a>            
        </footer>
    </div>
</div>
```

Or another way is not to use container and row divs for the footer. Just use the footer tag

```
        <footer id="footer" class="text-center">    
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/">
                <img class="instagram" src="instagram.png">
            </a>
            <a href="https://twitter.com/">
                <img class="icon" src="twitter.png">
            </a>
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/">
                <img class="icon" src="facebook.png">
            </a>            
        </footer>
```

Keep footer tag out of the section div and parallel to it.

```
<div class="carousel" data-interval="5000">
   <section class="container">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="container">
            <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
               <div class="carousel-inner">
                  <div class="item">
                     <img src="download.jpg" alt="Chicago" style="width:100%;">
                  </div>
                  <div class="item active">
                     <img src="download.jpg" alt="Chicago" style="width:100%;">
                  </div>
                  <div class="item">
                     <img src="download.jpg" "="" alt="Chicago" style="width:100%;">
                  </div>
                  <div class="item">
                     <img src="download.jpg" alt="Chicago" style="width:100%;">
                  </div>
                  <div class="item">
                     <img src="download.jpg" alt="Chicago" style="width:100%;">
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Left and right controls -->
            <!--  <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
               <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
               <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
               </a>
               <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
               <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
               <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
               </a>   -->
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
            <a name="About">
               <h1 class="col-sm-12">About</h1>
            </a>
            <h4 class="col-sm-12">Palacios Beauty Salon was founded filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler</h4>
            <img src="ab-seal-horizontal.png">
         </div>
      </div>
      <hr>
      <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
            <a name="Who We Are">
               <h1 class="col-sm-12">Who We Are</h1>
            </a>
            <div>
               <p class="col-sm-6">3 to 4 sentences about owner/founder of Palacios filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler filler</p>
               <p>
                  <img class="col-sm-6 img" src="blank.png">
               </p>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <hr>
      <div class="container">
         <div class="row">
            <a name="Services">
               <h1 class="col-sm-12">Services</h1>
            </a>
            <ul>
               <li class="col-sm-4">Manicure        $20</li>
               <li class="col-sm-4">Pedicure        $20</li>
               <li class="col-sm-4">Shampoo         $20</li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
      <hr>
   </section>
   <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
         <footer id="footer" class="text-center">   
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/">
            <img class="instagram" src="instagram.png">
            </a>
            <a href="https://twitter.com/">
            <img class="icon" src="twitter.png">
            </a>
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/">
            <img class="icon" src="facebook.png">
            </a>            
         </footer>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the help, it fixed the images but for some reason the container-fluid and removing the divs didnt help the the width. do you no why?

Comment: I need to see the code somewhere working for me to help you out. The snippets you provided above give no clue about your problem. I just suggested some general fixes that I felt was the problem. If you could provide some fiddle link may be i can help furher then

Comment: xenodochial-jepsen-daa504.bitballoon.com

Comment: Keep the footer tag parallel to the first section tag. See updated answer